# Issue with creating XMLQuery for given XPATH

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xmltype

I have a table having one columns as XMLTYPE being stored with Object-Relational storage. Below is table ddl.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders ( Order_id number not null,
                      Order_status Varchar2(100),
                      Order_desc XMLType not null)
                      XMLTYPE Order_desc STORE AS OBJECT RELATIONAL
                      XMLSCHEMA "http://localhost/public/xsd/Orderstore.xsd"
                      ELEMENT "OrderVal"
                     );
```

I have successfully registered the schema to load XSD with XML DB. Below is the XML being loaded into the XMLTYPE column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<draftorders>
  <OrderSumm>
     <Ordercod>OrderBookings</Ordercod>
  </OrderSumm>
  <Orderattrs>
     <Orderattr Ordername="HROrder">
        <OrderVals>
            <OrderVal>
                 <listvalue>Order1</listvalue>
                 <Orderattrs>
                      <Orderattr Ordername="Node1_Child1">
                         <OrderVals>
                             <OrderVal>
                                  <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node1_Child1_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                                  <Orderattrs>
                                       <Orderattr Ordername="Node2_Child1">
                                            <OrderVals>
                                                 <OrderVal>
                                                      <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                                                 </OrderVal>
                                            </OrderVals>
                                       </Orderattr>
                                       <Orderattr Ordername="Node2_Child2">
                                           <OrderVals>
                                                <OrderVal>
                                                      <listvalue><![CDATA[ Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1]]></listvalue>
                                                </OrderVal>
                                           </OrderVals>
                                       </Orderattr>
                                  </Orderattrs>
                             </OrderVal>
                         </OrderVals>
                      </Orderattr>
                 </Orderattrs>
            </OrderVal>
        </OrderVals>
     </Orderattr>
  </Orderattrs>
</draftorders>
```

I have the query using "extract" to print the below output:

```
SELECT     extract(o.Order_desc,'/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[0]/@Ordername').getStringVal() "Node1",
    extract(o.Order_desc,'/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[0]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/listvalue/text()').getStringVal() "Node1Child",
    extract(o.Order_desc,'/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/@Ordername').getStringVal() "Node2",
    extract(c.Order_desc,'/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/listvalue/text()').getStringVal() "Node2Child"
   FROM Orders o;

   OUTPUT:-               
   Node2_Child1
   Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1
   Node2_Child2
   Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1
```

I want to achieve the same output using XMLQuery, but I am unable to build query to print the child node. Till now, I can only print the node value using XMLQuery as given below:-

```
SELECT XMLQuery(            '/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[0]/@Ordername'
             PASSING o.Order_desc RETURNING CONTENT
           )
 FROM Orders o;
```

How can I achieve the same output from using "extract", with "XMLQuery" ?

Thanks.

/****************
Modified query run:-

```
SELECT XMLQuery('//OrderVal/Orderattrs/Orderattr/(@Ordername,   OrderVals/OrderVal/listvalue)/data(.)'
             PASSING o.Order_desc RETURNING CONTENT
           )
 FROM Orders o;
```

Output:-

```
Node2_Child1
Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1
Node2_Child
```

Fetching all Nodes and its child's using XMLTABLE.

```
SELECT ord.OrdName, ord.OrdVal
FROM Orders,   XMLTable('/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr[1]/OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/Orderattrs/Orderattr'
                 PASSING Order_desc
                 COLUMNS "OrdName"   VARCHAR2(4000) PATH '@Ordername',
                         "OrdVal"    VARCHAR2(4000) PATH  'OrderVals/OrderVal[1]/listvalue') ord;
```

Output:-

```
Node2_Child1
Node2_Child1_OrderValue_1
Node2_Child2  
Node2_Child2_OrderValue_1
......
Node2_Child2500
Node2_Child2500_OrderValue_1
```

How can I achieve the same using XMLQuery ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You queries and example XML do not seem to match, so I aligned to your queries as far as possible. As your XML was broken, too you might have to adjust some axis steps.

You can "branch" at some point (for example to fetch the attribute value and a subnode) using parentheses. This query will fetch all results at once for an arbitrary number of order attributes:

```
//OrderVal/Orderattrs/Orderattr/(@Ordername, OrderVals/OrderVal/listvalue)/data(.)
```

Comment: I have edited the XML, you can have a look at it. I tried to execute my query with you above comments, but got "No rows" output.

Comment: Modified the query as per your suggestions and pasted the output in my "Question" part...please see above.
The output is getting truncated...any clues why it is happening ?

And also what does "data(.)" does to the XMLQuery ??

Comment: Don't know why it gets truncated, only have few experience with Oracle DB. `data(.)` returns the data (attribute value/concatenated text nodes) of the current item.

Comment: Anybody can shed some light why I am getting truncated Output on running the Modified query please ?

Comment: So you were able to sort it out?

Comment: I was able to print all the nodes and its childs using XMLTABLE, but still not able to do it using XMLQuery. And also using "//" degrades performance, so cannot use it. Have updated the question with the option of using XMLTABLE, but how can I achieve the same using XMLQuery -- that is -- to print say all the nodes and its childs in an XML like the output I got from XMLTABLE ?

Comment: You don't need the `//` in the beginning, just replace by the necessary steps. I used it as I'm uncertain about what element will be root in Oracle XML (but you should be able to sort that out by trying out within less than a minute). By the way, are you sure it's not only some tool truncating the string but really Oracle DB? Do you get a single or multiple text/string items returned? Try removing the `/data(.)`.